# Alguém poderia me ajudar a alinhar?

Tags: html, css

[image]
[image]

```js
function Somar() {
  var somaN1 = window.document.querySelector('input#somaN1')
  var somaN2 = window.document.querySelector('input#somaN2')
  var somaRes = window.document.querySelector('span#somaRes')
  var somaN1 = Number.parseInt(somaN1.value)
  var somaN2 = Number.parseInt(somaN2.value)
  var soma = somaN1 + somaN2
  somaRes.innerHTML = `<strong>${soma}</strong>`
}

function Subtrair() {
  var subtracaoN1 = window.document.querySelector('input#subtracaoN1')
  var subtracaoN2 = window.document.querySelector('input#subtracaoN2')
  var subtracaoRes = window.document.querySelector('span#subtracaoRes')
  var subtracaoN1 = Number.parseInt(subtracaoN1.value)
  var subtracaoN2 = Number.parseInt(subtracaoN2.value)
  var subtracao = subtracaoN1 + subtracaoN2
  subtracaoRes.innerHTML = `<strong>${subtracao}</strong>`
}

function Multiplicar() {
  var multiplicacaoN1 = window.document.querySelector('input#multiplicacaoN1')
  var multiplicacaoN2 = window.document.querySelector('input#multiplicacaoN2')
  var multiplicacaoRes = window.document.querySelector('span#multiplicacaoRes')
  var multiplicacaoN1 = Number.parseInt(multiplicacaoN1.value)
  var multiplicacaoN2 = Number.parseInt(multiplicacaoN2.value)
  var multiplicacao = multiplicacaoN1 + multiplicacaoN2
  multiplicacaoRes.innerHTML = `<strong>${multiplicacao}</strong>`
}

function Dividir() {
  var divisaoN1 = window.document.querySelector('input#divisaoN1')
  var divisaoN2 = window.document.querySelector("input#divisaoN2")
  var divisaoRes = window.document.querySelector('span#divisaoRes')
  var divisaoN1 = Number.parseInt(divisaoN1.value)
  var divisaoN2 = Number.parseInt(divisaoN2.value)
  var divisao = divisaoN1 + divisaoN2
  divisaoRes.innerHTML = `<strong>${divisao}</strong>`
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Fazendo cálculos.</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font: normal 18pt Arial;
    }
    
    input.number {
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    span.aritmetico {
      outline-width: 300px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Cálculos a seguir:</h1>
  <div>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="somaN1">
    <span class="aritmetico">+</span>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="somaN2">
    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="Somar()">
    <span id="somaRes"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="subtracaoN1">
    <span class="aritmetico">-</span>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="subtracaoN2">
    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="Subtrair()">
    <span id="subtracaoRes"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="multiplicacaoN1">
    <span class="aritmetico">&times;</span>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="multiplicacaoN2">
    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="Multiplicar()">
    <span id="multiplicacaoRes"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="divisaoN1">
    <span class="aritmetico">&divide;</span>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="divisaoN2">
    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="Dividir()">
    <span id="divisaoRes"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Eu estou tentando a algum tempo alinhar os inputs da direita com apenas uma declaração CSS. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma boa forma de garantir largura e alinhamento dos item é a utilização do `inline-grid`, no seu caso, a utilização deve ser junto a definição da largura do elemento, ou seja `width:20px` e a definição do alinhamento dos elementos da classe `aritmetico` com a definição do `text-align:center`.

#### Seu código ficaria assim:

```js
function Somar() {
  var somaN1 = window.document.querySelector('input#somaN1')
  var somaN2 = window.document.querySelector('input#somaN2')
  var somaRes = window.document.querySelector('span#somaRes')
  var somaN1 = Number.parseInt(somaN1.value)
  var somaN2 = Number.parseInt(somaN2.value)
  var soma = somaN1 + somaN2
  somaRes.innerHTML = `<strong>${soma}</strong>`
}

function Subtrair() {
  var subtracaoN1 = window.document.querySelector('input#subtracaoN1')
  var subtracaoN2 = window.document.querySelector('input#subtracaoN2')
  var subtracaoRes = window.document.querySelector('span#subtracaoRes')
  var subtracaoN1 = Number.parseInt(subtracaoN1.value)
  var subtracaoN2 = Number.parseInt(subtracaoN2.value)
  var subtracao = subtracaoN1 - subtracaoN2
  subtracaoRes.innerHTML = `<strong>${subtracao}</strong>`
}

function Multiplicar() {
  var multiplicacaoN1 = window.document.querySelector('input#multiplicacaoN1')
  var multiplicacaoN2 = window.document.querySelector('input#multiplicacaoN2')
  var multiplicacaoRes = window.document.querySelector('span#multiplicacaoRes')
  var multiplicacaoN1 = Number.parseInt(multiplicacaoN1.value)
  var multiplicacaoN2 = Number.parseInt(multiplicacaoN2.value)
  var multiplicacao = multiplicacaoN1 * multiplicacaoN2
  multiplicacaoRes.innerHTML = `<strong>${multiplicacao}</strong>`
}

function Dividir() {
  var divisaoN1 = window.document.querySelector('input#divisaoN1')
  var divisaoN2 = window.document.querySelector("input#divisaoN2")
  var divisaoRes = window.document.querySelector('span#divisaoRes')
  var divisaoN1 = Number.parseInt(divisaoN1.value)
  var divisaoN2 = Number.parseInt(divisaoN2.value)
  var divisao = divisaoN1 / divisaoN2
  divisaoRes.innerHTML = `<strong>${divisao}</strong>`
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Fazendo cálculos.</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font: normal 18pt Arial;
    }
    
    input.number {
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    span.aritmetico {
      display: inline-grid;
      width: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Cálculos a seguir:</h1>
  <div>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="somaN1">
    <span class="aritmetico">+</span>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="somaN2">
    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="Somar()">
    <span id="somaRes"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="subtracaoN1">
    <span class="aritmetico">-</span>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="subtracaoN2">
    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="Subtrair()">
    <span id="subtracaoRes"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="multiplicacaoN1">
    <span class="aritmetico">&times;</span>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="multiplicacaoN2">
    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="Multiplicar()">
    <span id="multiplicacaoRes"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="divisaoN1">
    <span class="aritmetico">&divide;</span>
    <input type="number" class="number" id="divisaoN2">
    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="Dividir()">
    <span id="divisaoRes"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Além disso, corrigi as funções executadas no seu código, todas as operações estavam apenas somando.